# Finding area of a triangle

Tags: python, dictionary, geometry, area

My goal is to find the area of a triangle using the vertices that are in a dictionary.  For the sake of simplicity, i am using the coordinates (0,0), (1,0), and (0,2):

```
vertices = {1: (0,0), 2: (1,0), 3: (0,2)}
```

How can i access the specific numbers in each dictionary value?  As you can imagine, i would need each of these values to calculate the length of each side to find the area.  I have been researching the web for awhile but can't find any way to specifically access each number.

Comment: It would help if you specified which language you're working in.

Comment: im working in python

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like python. If this is the case, you'd access the members of the dictionary by name, as usual:

```
>>> vertices[1] 
(0,0)
```

and the points by index:

```
>>> v = vertices[1]
>>> x1 = v[0]
>>> x2 = v[1]
```

You can simplify this, of course:

```
>>> x1, x2 = vertices[1]
```

Is there any reason you're using a dict and not a list to contain the vertices? A list would probably be easier to work with.

Comment: I thought i would have to go about accessing them a different way but thank you.  I am only using a dictionary because it is in the parameters for the assignment.

Comment: It's always a good idea to do the assignment as written, even if it's not the ideal way to do it.